# Link all points to at least another one in a graph

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem where I need , given a graph find the minimal number of edges needed for that each vertex is linked to at least another one. To solve this problem I tried doing this method in pseudo-code:

```
getEdgesCount(listOfPoints):
linkedPoints = set()
edgeCount = 0

for point in listOfPoints:
    alternative = None
    best = None
    foundEdge = false
    if point not in linkedPoints:
         for secondPoint in listOfPoints:
             if secondPoint != point:
                 if canLink(secondPoint,point):
                     if secondPoint in linkedPoints:
                         alternative = secondPoint
                         foundEdge = true
                     else:
                         best = secondPoint
                         foundEdge = true
                         break
        if foundEdge:
            linkedPoints.push(point)
            edgeCount++
            if best != None:
                linkedPoints.push(best)
            else:
                linkedPoints.push(alternative)
return edgeCount
```

But this code seems to not always give the right answer, meaning it counts to much edges , so I ask you what is wrong in this code ?

I maybe mis-interpreted the problem , here is how it stands :
You have a set of `n` points , and you have provided all the two points pairs that **can't** be linked together , you have to get the minimum edges such that any given point is connected to at least another one.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with your exercise. 1.) You should better ask such theoretical things in the "Computer Science" community. 2.) The exercise as described is trivial. Take a list of all lonely vertices and connect them pairwise. You will need half as much edges as you find lonely vertices. 3.) I guess your exercise is different, like "make the tree connected".

Comment: I edited the post to show the real problem , is this really the way to go ?

Comment: I restriction "you have provided all the two points pairs that can't be linked together" is the point of matter. This will prevent from stupidly pairwise connect consecutive points of a list of lonely points. Now the exercise no longer trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at a configuration and how it fails in your case:

- A connectible to C
- B connectible to D
- A connectible to B (but not needed)

Your algorithm will

1. connect A and B first
2. find C to only be connectible to A
3. find D to only be connectible to B

So you need 3 edges instead of 2. You must find sets of connectible points (like A,B,C,D) and connect points with fewest opportunities first. In our example C-A-B-D is such a set. C has just one opportunity so we connect C-A remaining B-D.

A better but still greedy and thus not optimal algorithm would be:

1. Search the lonely point with the fewest possible connections.
2. In the set of possible partners take again the one with the fewest possible connections and connect it to the first one.
3. Repeat 1. until all connections between pairwise lonely points are done.
4. Do the same with connections of lonely points to non lonely points.

Example (triangles at ends of line):

- Possible connections:

  - A to B
  - B to C
  - A to D
  - D to B
  - C to E
  - E to F
  - F to C
- Number of possible connections (sorted)

  - A:2
  - D:2
  - E:2
  - F:2
  - B:3
  - C:3
- A has only 2 possible connections (A-B or A-D)

  - B has 3 and D only 2 => connect A-D
- Number of remaining possible connections of remaining points

  - B:1
  - E:2
  - F:2
  - C:3
- B has only 1 possible connection => connect B-C
- Number of remaining possible connections of remaining points

  - E:1
  - F:1
- E has only 1 possible connection => connect E-F
- **Solved**

But this is by far not the most complicated case. The problem can't be optimal solved by a [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm). If you e.g. think of two possible pentagons (instead of triangles) connected by one edge you will find, that connecting any pair with fewest possible connections still will fail to find the optimal solution. The pentagon case can be solved with 5 edges, but only if you start with the correct pair.

Good luck and have fun.

Comment: meaning I need to Do an algorithm that A. scans all the node and register how much nodes it connects to , and B. connect the nodes by checking the nodes with the least potential connections first ?

Comment: Yes and that first for connections to other lonely nodes and later for the rest. The order is essential for the optimal solution. I hope the example C-A-B-D is making this clear. Connecting the first two (A-B) is a fault.

Comment: So the algorithm is like find all points that can connect ton only **1** other point , and connect them to any other like this , and with the remaining points do the stuff I did earlier is that all there is to it ?

Comment: Not exactly. There are more complicated cases than just points with one possible connection. Building a connection is a double sided action. So take care about possible connections at both sides. Just think about things like a triangle at the end of a line and have a look at the minimal and not minimal solutions possible (see edited answer above).

Answer (score -1):

This is a graph traversal problem and you can pick any flavor that you like:

- BFS: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/
- DFS: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/

Obviously if the graph is made up of unconnected components, then there is not solution. This can be easily checked with the DFS algorithm linked above.

Comment: The question is not about travelling existing connections but about building new once. Neither BFS nor DFS will help.